# How to re-install EAP 802.1x authentication methods?

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, sony-xperia

Is there any way to reinstall the EAP authentication methods? or Am I doomed to do a factory reset?
I can't connect to my enterprise Wi-Fi because it only has "EAP-SIM" selected and there's no way to change it.

I've tried creating it manually but still it only shows "EAP-SIM", It's stuck in that method and grayed out always.

[image: Add Network Manually stuck on EAP-SIM]

Additional Info:

- Model number: F3213 (Sony XPeria XA Ultra)
- Android Version: 7.0
- Android Security patch level: May 5, 2017
- Baseband version: MOLY.LR11.W1603.MD.TC9.SP.... (is this needed?)
- Kernel Version: 3.18.35+
- Build number: 36.1.A.0.182
- Service Provider: Telcel (Mexico)

PS: Can someone create a "802.1x" or "EAP" or "Authentication method" tag? Or that's not much of interest in here?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the phone. The EAP method is greyed out with the sim option selected. I did however manage to change it after playing with it for some time. For reasons unknown, the option did eventually become available to me by just trying to modify the settings then exiting and repeating that process. Once the option becomes available it did not remain available for long. As far as I looked there is no current fix, I hope this works for you too.

Hope you come right with you problem.
Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to send my phone to Tech Support for another reason (overheating due to GPS), which also required flashing the memory, with Sony's Android. So, I couldn't find a "real solution" but thanks, I think I'll mark it as correct in few months, to see if someone else answers when "bumped to the top" by the stackexchange bot.